# Azimuth vs Yaw?

Tags: geometry

What is the difference between these two terms, or are they completely synonymous?  I have frequently seen either used in connection with pitch and roll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are others probably more qualified to speak on this subject than I, but from what I've gleaned from the Wikipedia pages on [Azimuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth) and [Yaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaw_%28rotation%29):

Azimuth seems to be used to represent an absolute heading, while yaw is a measurement of how much a craft turns from its current orientation.

Thus, if your azimuth went from $90^\circ$ to $184^\circ$, your yaw was $94^\circ$, while your current azimuth is $184^\circ$.

Comment: So yaw is merely change in azimuth?  It just seems odd, considering that I know that the corresponding terms for the other axes--pitch and roll--are commonly used both to describe absolute orientation and change of orientation.

Comment: I will give a disclaimer that I *could* be wrong.  However, upon reading those wiki articles (and from what else I've read when looking at compass sensors), I see azimuth always referring to absolute heading.  Yaw I typically see referring to change in heading: http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&safe=active&tbo=u&as_qdr=all&q=yaw&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=fysUUe3KH6aE2wWd34H4Cg&ved=0CC8QkQ4&biw=1205&bih=684

Comment: Yaw is in the vehicle's coordinate system. Azimuth is global. Pitch up 180 degrees then yaw 180 degrees, you're at the initial azimuth except upside-down (in 180 degree roll).